# nullpointer exception at onServiceConnected()

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, onserviceconnected

**Edit 2 :
I just realized that I didn't initialize info with new AccessibilityServiceInfo , I'm just stupid.**

I'm trying to use AccessibilityService to listen and retrieve information of notifications from my other apps to the phone (youtube , facebook, sms)

It crashes and the logcat report null pointer exception on onServiceConnected

After googling I think it might be due to the activity has not yet bind to the service and thus could not launch it ?

Do I need to bind an accessibility service?

If so how do I do it ?

I have these codes in my AccessibilityListener class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        Log.d("TAG","onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        info.packageNames = new String[] {"com.whatsapp","com.facebook"};

        info.notificationTimeout = 100;

        this.setServiceInfo(info);
        Log.d("TAG","onServiceConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        final int eventType = event.getEventType();
        NotificationInfo info = new NotificationInfo();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Received event", 1000);
        Log.d("TAG","onaccessibility event running");
        switch (eventType) {

            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
                info.packageName = (String) event.getPackageName();
                info.eventTime = event.getEventTime();
                info.eventText = event.getText().toString();
                sendEvent(info);


        }
    }
```

and these codes in my activity

```
@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //sets the main layout of the activity

    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_display);


    //initializes the calendarview

    initializeCalendar();

    intent = new Intent(this,AccessibilityListener.class);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to Your Service
   // Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccessibilityListener.class);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(notificationReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter("add-event"));
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(isMyServiceRunning(AccessibilityListener.class))
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service is online", 1000).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service is offline", 1000).show();

    registerReceiver(notificationReceiver,new IntentFilter(AccessibilityListener.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}
```

Edit : As requested , added in logcat

```
> 08-25 07:35:29.265: D/ActivityThread(24456): handleBindApplication:com.example.utarapp
08-25 07:35:29.265: D/ActivityThread(24456): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
08-25 07:35:29.265: D/ActivityThread(24456): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
08-25 07:35:29.630: D/TAG(24456): onCreate
08-25 07:35:29.715: D/libEGL(24456): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
08-25 07:35:29.725: D/libEGL(24456): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
08-25 07:35:29.730: D/libEGL(24456): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
08-25 07:35:29.730: E/(24456): Device driver API match
08-25 07:35:29.730: E/(24456): Device driver API version: 23
08-25 07:35:29.730: E/(24456): User space API version: 23 
08-25 07:35:29.730: E/(24456): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014 
08-25 07:35:29.830: D/OpenGLRenderer(24456): Enabling debug mode 0
08-25 07:35:30.150: D/AndroidRuntime(24456): Shutting down VM
08-25 07:35:30.150: W/dalvikvm(24456): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4185ace0)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456): Process: com.example.utarapp, PID: 24456
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at com.example.utarapp.AccessibilityListener.onServiceConnected(AccessibilityListener.java:36)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$1.onServiceConnected(AccessibilityService.java:546)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:659)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
08-25 07:35:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(24456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 07:35:32.080: I/Process(24456): Sending signal. PID: 24456 SIG: 9
08-25 07:35:33.165: D/ActivityThread(24700): handleBindApplication:com.example.utarapp
08-25 07:35:33.165: D/ActivityThread(24700): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
08-25 07:35:33.165: D/ActivityThread(24700): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
08-25 07:35:33.225: D/TAG(24700): onCreate
08-25 07:35:33.235: D/AndroidRuntime(24700): Shutting down VM
08-25 07:35:33.235: W/dalvikvm(24700): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4185ace0)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700): Process: com.example.utarapp, PID: 24700
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at com.example.utarapp.AccessibilityListener.onServiceConnected(AccessibilityListener.java:36)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$1.onServiceConnected(AccessibilityService.java:546)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:659)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
08-25 07:35:33.240: E/AndroidRuntime(24700):    at 

    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-25 07:40:33.305: I/Process(24700): Sending signal. PID: 24700 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you show us the logcat? Also, is 'info' giving you the NPE?

Comment: Which of these is line 36?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mention from hitch.united , I realised it is due to me not initializing

AccessibilityServiceInfo

I works after I info= new AccessibilityServiceInfo()

Sorry my mistake.

Comment: NullPointerExceptions are always about something Null, that hasn't been initialized. Take care next time :)

Comment: working in all device very well but in redmi devices it getting null pointer exception what is the issue